# Submit formulario criando novo produto Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Não sei se é o melhor lugar, mas em outros lugares não me deram devida atenção

é o seguinte: estou tentando de varias maneiras enviar dados de um formulário para um novo produto de woocommerce. O usuário digita os valores e esses valores caem direto criando um novo produto. Mas a questão é que existem taxonomias criadas que não estão sendo armazenadas no produto (vou deixar um link de imagem)
O produto novo contem titulo, preço , descrição, categoria, so essas taxonomias que continuam vazias
Fiz o formulario com o Gravity forms custom posts

Muito obrigado!

https://prnt.sc/Sio6DO3zMFXf
https://prnt.sc/XeujUKY2izwc
https://prnt.sc/y3H_hroTJT55

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Esse site é um Q&A temático sobre linguagens de programação e seu problema não parece ser um problema específico sobre linguagens de programação, parece mais um com um ajuste de plugin. Além desse site aqui nossa comunidade também conta com o site [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) que é um Q&A especializado em Wordpress e seus plugins. Possivelmente esse site seja o mais adequado a recepcionar a sua pergunta, lembrando que site é voltado a comunidade internacional e toda a comunicação deve ser feita em lígua inglesa.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta inserir o post mais ou menos assim:

$id = wp_insert_post( $seu_post_aqui );
wp_set_object_terms( $id , 'item_que_deseja_inserir', 'nome_do_termo' );

se for vários pode até criar um laço:

$terms = array(
'term_1' => 'valor do terme',
'term_2' => 'valor do terme',
'term_3' => 'valor do terme',
'term_4' => 'valor do terme',
);

foreach($terms as $key => $value):
wp_set_object_terms( $id , $value, $key );
endforeach;

agora só testando...
referência tá aqui : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).